# How to prevent 'type-jacking'?

Tags: javascript, html, security, web

Let's say I own a social media website. I want to implement an iframe which allows users to sign up to my site, via 3rd party sites -- much like facebook's 'like this' iframes, but for signup.

(This is just a hypothetical example by the way, I'm more interested in the security implications of iframes being used on 3rd party sites in this and other ways).

In order to do this, how can I prevent the following situation:

- A 3rd party site includes an iframe pointing to my site's signup flow
- They position text boxes on their own site ABOVE the iframe, mimicking the 'email/password' fields for my signup form
- They then harvest user emails and passwords when people attempt to sign up.

One thing I can think of which might mitigate this is randomly positioning elements within the iframe.

Can anyone think of any other ways to target this kind of attack?

Comment: That's called phishing.  You can't mitigate it at all; a site can spoof your login page without involving you at all.

Comment: Have your "login page" consist of nothing more than a link. When the link is clicked, a new page is opened where the actual login is done. However, nothing prevents a malicious site from re-creating your login page on their own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides not posting a login on a 3rd party site within an iFrame? None...

It's phishing scams not injection or anything else you can protect against - Especially since it's not on your site...

You could random generate or anything else you want, all someone has to do is reverse-engineer what you've done to mimic it...